# Each Database Operation takes 30 seconds

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go-driver

Even the simplest code:

```golang
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb+srv://standard:example@cluster0.f5yec.mongodb.net/blog-application?retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connect to DB: ", err.Error())
    }
    db := client.Database("blog-application")
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Second()) // 9
    db.Collection("user").Find(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Second()) // 39
}
```

takes 30 seconds to run.

Why does it need that long to run?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The way you measure time is flawed. I'm not saying it's not 30 seconds but, based on the output, it could just as well be 1 minute and 30 seconds, or 1 hour 27 minutes and 30 seconds, or whatever and 30 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but when I run it I notice it takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no error checking on the find. Your find fails because your client can't connect to your cluster, and the default  server selection timeout is 30 seconds.

"Each database operation takes 30 seconds" is only partially true. Each *attempt* at a database operation takes 30 seconds before it fails.